# How to detect when app is minized in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to detect when the app has been minimized? Simply using `WidgetsBindingObserver` with the `paused` event doesn't work as it's indistinguishable from when the user turns off the screen / phone locks. Note, I need this to work for both android and ios.

A bit of context of what I'm doing. In the application, I'm running a timer. I want to stop this timer if the user minimizes the app (e.g. uses its phone for something else). If the user, however, turns off the screen/locks it, I want the timer to continue.

Comment: Are you using the 4 states of AppLifecycleState?

Comment: well yes, it's just that these 4 states don't give enough info. it's paused -> inactive for  both minimizing the app and locking the phone. Note, I need this to work for both android and IOS

Comment: Can you give us a snippet of your code?

Comment: It' 1 to 1 to any `WidgetsBindingObserver` implementation. It's just that the 4 states don't capture the difference between minimized and screen off.

Comment: Ok I hadn't get it. Why do you need to make the difference between minimized and screen off?

Comment: I need to execute some code when the user minimizes the app. Basically do exactly the same as "Forest" application: stop a timer when the app is minimised but not when the screen turns off

Comment: Check this dependency - https://pub.dev/packages/is_lock_screen

Comment: Interesting! This plugin hacks around the issue by using screen brightness. Will give it a go, though as mentioned seems a bit hacky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to take a look at this package: [is_lock_screen](https://pub.dev/packages/is_lock_screen)

As the description suggest

> Useful for determining whether app entered background due to locking screen or leaving app.

I would try with this:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
    final isLock = await isLockScreen();
    if(!isLock){
       print('app inactive MINIMIZED!');
    }
    print('app inactive in lock screen!');
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    print('app resumed');
  }
}
```

Comment: Careful, you shouldn't make method such as this one asynchronous to use await inside.

Comment: Can you explain (or link to an article) why you shouldn't use async in this situation? I don't feel like it could cause any damage as long as "isLockSCreen()" gets resolved.

Comment: After testing this, it seems to be working. nice one

Comment: Just to point it out, I did a mistake in the lock screen print, it should be in a "else" branch

Answer (score 3):

Above solution is also good but if you prefer not to import any library.

You just simply need to `observe` your `WidgetBinding` in initial screen and listen it.

Include abstract class `WidgetsBindingObserver` in your initial screen like splash screen:

```
class _SplashState extends State<Splash> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
```

Implement Observer in `initState` to observer app state:

```
@override
void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  super.initState();
}
```

and then finally track app lifecycle by this method

```
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
switch (state) {
  case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
    print('Back to app');
    break;
  case AppLifecycleState.paused:
    print('App minimised or Screen locked');
    break;
  }
}
```